# I can't figure out what is wrong with this regular expression

Tags: regex, vbscript

So the I wrote the following vbscript to read a file that the command line would output. The contents of the file would simply be (COMx) with x being the port number of the device in question. This script is supposed to read that file and pull out 'x' and save it to a new text file. I wrote this about two weeks ago and tested it, it worked. Now it seems that no matter what I do I can't get work at all. This is just so baffling to as IT WORKED two weeks ago. Now it just creates an output file with nothing in it. I don't know if I accidentally changed something or what, but any help would be appreciated.

```
Const ForReading = 1  
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\rtlstuff\COM.txt", ForReading)  
strContents = objFile.ReadAll  
objFile.Close  

Set regex = New RegExp 
    With regex 
        .Pattern = ".*\(COM(.+)?\).*" 
    End With 

Dim ComPort 
If regex.Test(strContents) Then 
    ComPort = regex.Replace(strContents,"$1") 
End If 

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
outFile="c:\rtlstuff\ComPort.txt" 
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True) 
objFile.Write ComPort 
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex seems like overkill. If you know the line just contains "COMx", why not just use one of these methods?

```
' Option 1: Start at the 4th char...
strContents = Mid(objFile.ReadLine, 4)

' Option 2: Remove "COM" from the line...
strContents = Replace(objFile.ReadLine, "COM", "")
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, the regex was leftover from the file output had a lot more useless text in it.